How to disable "Space to select" in Ubuntu filepicker?
This is very annoying and happens all the time, I want to search for a file with spaces, for example: 2025 02 22 Wedding, and as soon as I write "2025<space" it picks the first file which is not what I wanted. I have to manually go to the search bar click there to enter the space.
This is very counter intuitive since you were writing for a name and suddenly a normal character in a file name becomes the "Enter".
Is there a way to disable this?


This is indeed poor implementation, and can be considered a design issue. There is no way to change that behavior than to change the inner workings of the dialog, i.e., edit the source code and recompile. If the issue is not yet known to the developpers, it would be worthwhile to file it.
There is work ongoing to replace the gtk-filechooser by the file browser nautilus. That will resolve a lot of perks that exist with the filechooser dialog.
